# Prove that $\beta(G) \geq \frac{n}{\Delta+1}$

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

Prove that if $G$ is a graph of order $n$, maximum degree $\Delta$ and having no isolated vertices, then $\beta(G) \geq \frac{n}{\Delta+1}$, where $\beta(G)$ denotes the size of the minimum vertex cover of $G$.

My attempt:  I'm attempting to solve this by induction on $n$, where the base case is $n=2$ which holds pretty trivially.  Now I assume this is true for all $n$ and show this to be true for $n+1$ vertices.  Now consider the graph $G+\{u\}$ on $n+1$ vertices, now I split the proof up into cases,

Case 1:  The vertex $u$ is connected to one of the vertices that make up the minimum vertex covering and thus $\beta(G+\{u\})=\beta(G)$.  Now notice that since $$\beta(G) \geq \frac{n}{\Delta+1} \implies \beta(G) \geq \left\lceil\frac{n}{\Delta+1}\right\rceil=k=\left\lceil\frac{(n+1)}{(\Delta+1)+1}\right\rceil$$ Now since $\beta(G) \in \mathbb{N}$ we conclude that $\beta(G) \geq \frac{n+1}{\Delta+2}$ as required.

Case 2: The new vertex $u$ is not connected to any vertex in the minimum vertex cover and thus $\beta(G+\{u\})=\beta(G)+1$.  Now I am not sure how to proceed, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the induction approach is going to work out precisely because your second case is tricky to deal with: $G$ might have multiple minimum vertex covers, and $G + \{u\}$ might have a completely different set of minimum vertex covers that have nothing to do with those, for all we know.

(Also, the bounds $\frac{n}{\Delta(G)+1}$ and $\frac{n+1}{\Delta(G+\{u\}) + 1}$ are hard to relate to each other.)

But there is a direct proof that does not use induction.

**Hint:** If $G$ has a vertex cover $C \subseteq V(G)$ with $|C| =\beta(G)$, then the vertices of $C$ can have at most $|C| \Delta(G)$ neighbors total.

Comment: a vetex $v \in C$ could have anywhere from 1 to $n-1$ neighbors correct? Then the whole graph can have $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ neighbors combined.

Comment: Well, if it had $n-1$ neighbors, we'd have $\Delta(G)=n-1$.

Comment: in which case the proposition holds, what can we do for any other amount of neighbors?

Comment: See what you get if you work through the algebra in terms of $\Delta$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the algebra in terms of $\Delta$

Comment: In terms of $\Delta$ and $|C|$, what is the maximum number of neighbors that $C$ can have?

Comment: is it $|C|+\Delta$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56281/discussion-between-misha-and-justin-stevenson).

Comment: I don't understand how to use the hint. Would you please explain with more detail?